# Drop event not firing on wpf context menu

Tags: c#, wpf

I have been trying to drag some information from my application to a sub menu in a button.

I can drop the information in any element on the system but it doesn't work on the sub menu that I have created using the context menu.

I created an example using a textbox and a button with a context menu.

When I try to drag the text and drop it in a context menu item the drop event is not fired.

Do you guys have any idea what could be happening?

Xaml:

```
<Button Height="30" Width="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" AllowDrop="True" DragEnter="Button_DragEnter" >
    Context
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu AllowDrop="True">
            <MenuItem Header="Text1" AllowDrop="True" Drop="MenuItem_Drop" />
            <MenuItem Header="Text2" AllowDrop="True" Drop="MenuItem_Drop" />
            <MenuItem Header="Text3" AllowDrop="True" Drop="MenuItem_Drop" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>

</Button>
```

C#:

```
private void Button_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    Button bt = sender as Button;
    if (!bt.ContextMenu.IsOpen)
        bt.ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
}
private void MenuItem_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    MenuItem menuItem = sender as MenuItem;
    MessageBox.Show("Drop on the" + menuItem.Header + " data = " + e.Data.GetData(typeof(string)));
}
```

OBS: when I drag from outside of my application the drop works well